# Is it correct and natural to say "push something on someone" meaning to sell something to someone they don't need?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *push something on someone* meaning to sell something to someone they don't need? For example:

> The salesman was so slick that he managed to **push** a totally useless thing **on**  a few people.

If it sounds off, would you tell me what you would say to communicate the meaning?

Comment: Yes, it is an idiomatic expression.

Answer (score -1):

"To push something on someone" is not a set phrase; here are a few with [push](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+something+on+someone). You can use ***force something on someone*** instead:

> to make someone do or accept something even though they do not want to
>
> - It’s no good trying to ***force** a diet **on** someone*. ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/force-on-upon))

Comment: Yes, in fact, it is a "set phrase" aka idiomatic expression.

Comment: It's certainly a set phrase in Canada, where I'm from.